# Android CAB listview state_selected and state_pressed

Tags: android, android-listview, android-selector, android-contextmenu

I have a problem: I have a ListView with a MULTI_CHOICE listener that opens up the ContextualActionBar. For each item in this list I've setted a backround on the root layout. This is the XML:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/light_blue_alpha"
      android:state_activated="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@color/light_blue"
      android:state_pressed="true"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/card_background"/>
```

In this case the default background is a card layout (basically white). When the item is pressed the background is a full light blue. When activated (through CAB choice) the background is a ligh blue with 0.5 alpha.

This is what is happening:
I start the CAB. If I select a new item during the CAB, the item changes its background to `light_blue` (while pressed). When I release the finger it changes to the default background `card_background`. A few milliseconds later it gets activated and then changes to `light_blue_alpha`

So basically I'm getting this kind of flickering blue-white-blue. What I want to achieve is to "remove" the white background transaction. I see for example that Gmail app does exactly what I want to do.

How can achieve that? Thank you!!

EDIT:
I tried moving all to a root listSelector. This is the selector:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@color/light_blue"/>
<item android:state_activated="true"  android:drawable="@color/light_blue_alpha"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

I also set drawOnTop to true, and the pressed background is correctly applied. But the state_activated doesn't! When I start the CAB, the item returns to its default background. Why doesn't it take the state_activated background??

Comment: Can you attach `what is happening` and `what you want to acheive` :)

Comment: That's right. But I'm alright able to do that. The problem is that when I release the finger on the item, the item falls back to its default background and after a few millisecond gets activated so it goes to the activated background. I want to disable or hide finger release effect. I want the item to go from the pressed background to the activated background DIRECTLY

Answer (score 0):

take one variable in adapter named as selected_position, assign selected position value in this variable.

call notifydatasetchanged method for adapter

in get view method put condition like

if(selected_position == position)
{
   change back ground color of list item
}
else
{
    set default background color
}

Hope this helps

Comment: mmh.. Do I realy need to put hands on java code? If I don't find any solution I will go with this one